# How to understand whether the user scrolled to the end of the list or to the beginning ListView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a ListView control, it stores a list of messages (chat). How to understand if the user scrolled to the end of the list or if he is somewhere at the beginning.

My ListView xaml

```
<ListView
              
                ItemTapped="MyListView_ItemTapped"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
                RefreshCommand="{Binding UpdateList}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}"
                Background="#1D2733" 
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
                RefreshControlColor="Cyan"  
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                SeparatorColor="Transparent"  
                x:Name="MyListView" 
                HasUnevenRows="true" 
                >
               
            </ListView>
```

Result Code:
[image: MyChat]

Comment: I've read your question. You might be able to set the scrolled event handler in your listview, just like:<ListView Scrolled="OnListViewScrolled">.
And then you may set an event handler. You may try this idea first.

Comment: @Hongxin Sui, I was able to get the coordinates (X,Y), but when I add new items to the list, the Y coordinate becomes larger. or when I open the keyboard. How do I then understand where the end of the list is if it is constantly dynamic

Comment: Maybe you can try this： getLastVisiblePosition() == (getCount() - 1) //判断滚动到底部
getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 //判断滚动到顶部